# How do I create and point a new perforce workspace to an existing folder?

Tags: perforce

So I have a folder that has a nice big 50GB depot in it that I pulled down from another machine.  I've copied this folder over to a second machine and I want to run an update on this folder from perforce however it forces me to download the entire folder and all of the contents over again instead of just updating the new content.

My question is, how do I create a new workspace, set it's root to a folder that is already populated with a depot, and not be forced to redownload the whole folder once I run an update?

Answer (score 6):

Use "p4 sync -k", aka "p4 flush".

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/2446

After flushing the workspace, I recommend running "p4 clean", which will verify the workspace contents and force an update of anything that doesn't match what you just flushed to.

Comment: How to do this in p4v?

Comment: You can't.  Most "advanced" Perforce tasks and/or optimizations of large operations require use of the command line; if you don't want to use the command line, you'll need to just re-sync the entire folder from P4V.